# How to get the multiples of 3 or 5 in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

How can I get the multiples of 3 or 5 in vb.net? I have this code but it gives me different  output. Please help me.

```
   Dim x As Integer
    For x = 3 To 10
        If x Mod 2 <> 0 Then
            Dim sum As Integer
            sum += x
            MsgBox(x)
        End If
    Next
```

The output will be `3,5,7,9`. The expected output should be `3,5,6,9`. So any help?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what are you using `sum` for? Note too that your code is just looking for odd numbers (that's what `Mod 2 <> 0` does)

Comment: Sorry for that, I want to get the sum of the numbers which is multiples of 3 or 5.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`x Mod 2 <> 0` gives you all numbers except numbers that are divisible  by 2. But you want all numbers that are divisible  by 3 or 5.

So this gives you the expected output:

```
For x = 3 To 9
    If x Mod 3 = 0 OrElse x Mod 5 = 0 Then
    ' ... '
```

Note that my loops ends with 9 instead of 10 since 10 would be divisible  by 5 but you dont expect it.

Answer (score 3):

```
For Each i As Integer In Enumerable.Range(1,10) _
              .Where(Function(i) i Mod 3 = 0 OrElse i Mod 5 = 0)

    MsgBox(i)
Next i
```

Answer (score 2):

Why do you check `x Mod 2 <> 0`, when you need multiplies of 3 and 5? Try following:

```
Dim x As Integer
For x = 3 To 10
    If x Mod 3 = 0 OrElse x Mod 5 = 0 Then
        Dim sum As Integer
        sum += x
        MsgBox(x)
    End If
Next
```